# Looking for Android reference/information

Tags: android

I'm asking here since I can't seem to find answers elsewhere. I've been dabbling in Android programming and I've pretty much been just following examples and piecing together different snippets without really understanding the methodology behind it. Can someone point me in the direction of such a resource or reference that could perhaps break down what I'm looking at?

Comment: You're going to spend a lot of time here if you haven't already. http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Comment: Yes, I've been on there more times than I can count. I've already done their tutorial, etc. But there is ever hardly anything explaining "X does this because Y" or something. The first example of this that comes to mind is say adapters. More specifically I was looking for more of how a function/snippet is used and how to modify/change it.

Comment: http://androidtutorialonline.com/ultimate-android-reference/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to Android development then [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/) is gonna be so useful for you and it's also available in [pdf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_pdf_version.htm) format so you can learn offline too. Every concept defined here is very well and if you still need explicit description then [Android's Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) is always there for you.

Comment: That is perfect!! I hadn't run across tutorials point before! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: http://androidtutorialonline.com/ultimate-android-reference/ site will five unlimited android reference